# Adding mySql to eclipse project with maven tomcat plugin

Tags: mysql, spring, maven, maven-tomcat-plugin, maven-eclipse-plugin

I have a spring mvc project downloaded from the web and fully working. I'm using maven and maven tomcat plugin to manage dependencies and to run the webapp in the built-in tomcat. I'm trying to add mySql support in my project. Since i'm new to maven and maven tomcat plugin, I don't know hot to do this. Before i tried to add mysql, all was working and i was able to launch my web app simply executing a tomcat:run maven goal.

For now, when i execute tomcat:run i get a

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Here is what i've already done after some reading around the web:
I added dependencies for mysql driver (and Hibernate annotations too since i want to use it) in my pom.xml, and specified the dependency for tomcat plugin:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.9</version>
```

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
<configuration>
        <mode>context</mode>
    </configuration>
<dependencies>      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</plugin>
```

You can also notice a  tag to specify to use a context.xml file. But I don't know where to put this file. I readed it should be generated automatically in tomcat/conf, but it's not present. So i added it manually with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
     <Resource name="jdbc/mkyongdb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="root" password="password" 
           driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mkyongdb"/>

</Context>
```

Then in web.xml, located in tomcat/conf i added:

```
<resource-ref>
<description>MySQL Datasource example</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/mkyongdb</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

I placed the same content in src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml and in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

With all these configuration, the error mentioned above doesn't appears. But if i try to use hibernate adding

```
<bean id="dataSource" 
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mkyongdb" />
<property name="username" value="root" />
<property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
<bean
    id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" >
    <property name="dataSource" >
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties" >
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" >create-drop</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect" >org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql" >true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses" >
        <list>
            <value>org.mose.grouporganizer.entity.AccelerometerFeatures</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

then i get the comunication link failure. What i'm missing?
If it's needed i can add the full stack trace.

Comment: did u solve this problem?how

Answer (score 0):

If your application works fine and you want to use MySQL as your database then you should add MySQL driver in your `pom.xml` and change Hibernate configuration. That it.

Comment: As I wrote, I already did it, but it didn't worked! Don't I need to configure tomcat plugin? Please explaine little more..

Comment: You wrote that you have working application running on Tomcat? Using what database?

Comment: Hmm... In this case check if your MySQL is working and you can connect to it using console. Also see full stack trace of your exception.

Answer (score 0):

First upgrade to last tomcat maven plugin which is now at Apache.

See http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/

Regarding the context use

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <contextFile>path to your context file</contextFile>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: with tomcat7:run i get: `Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:jar:2.0 (): Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-parent:pom:10 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 60000 -> [Help 1]`

Comment: It looks maven central had some issues yesterday. 
So try again with -U